# handle text html in j2me

Tags: html, xml, java-me, midp, lcdui

I tried to make application RSS news, and  it can give detail news to user.

When I go to detail, the body text is show the html tag.

This is picture of my application:

> [image: from img855.imageshack.us/img855/5782/detailz.png]

I don't want to show html tags.

This is my code to show detail page:

```
private void detailScreen(News news){
    Form form = new Form(news.getTitle());

    StringItem detail = new StringItem("", news.getBody().toString());
    mBackCommand = new Command("Back", Command.BACK, 0);

    form.append(detail);
    form.addCommand(mBackCommand);
    form.setCommandListener(this);

    //Canvas c = new MyCanvas(this, news);

    mDisplay.setCurrent(form);
}
```

Please can someone tell me what's I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: of options suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9715632/839601), [PocketLearn J2ME HTML Component](http://www.j2mehtml.com/j2mehtml/index.htm) looks worth considering. _"...solution for rendering HTML on MIDP 2.0 devices..."_