# html text Extraction between multiple div tags in j2me

Tags: jquery, html, java-me, lwuit

I have a html web page url http://teluguone.com/recipes/content/Andhra-Spicy-Mutton-Curry-Recipe-6-221.html

I need to extract Description text from the above url.

My Requirement is, I need to get the text with html tags between multiple DIV tags,

Example:

```
<div class="relatedarticals_info_bold"><h1>Recipe Name</h1></div> : Andhra Spicy Mutton Curry Recipe</div> 
</div> <div id="relatedarticals_info2"> <div class="relatedarticals_info"> <div class="relatedarticals_info_bold">
<h1>Author</h1></div> : Teluguone</div> </div> <div id="relatedarticals_info2"> <div class="relatedarticals_info">
 <div class="relatedarticals_info_bold"><h1>Preparation Time</h1></div> : 30 Mins</div> </div>etc.....?
```

I need to get the output like this:

```
Recipe Name: Andhra Spicy Mutton Curry Recipe Author: Teluguone 
Preparation Time: 30 Mins etc...
```

Comment: You might be in need of an html parser for Java ME. Take a look at the options listed at this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715597/handle-text-html-in-j2me

Comment: initially,i dont require pure text,i require the whole text with some tags between div tags,after i extracted the whole text with some tags,i have a code to remove the tags from a string and outputs a pure text

Comment: initially,i need a code to extract a text with some tags between multiple div tags?

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand what you need. :(

Comment: Hi Telmo Pimentel Mota,                                
My Actual Requirement is,i need to get the text with html tags between multiple DIV tags,Example:

<div class="relatedarticals_info_bold"><h1>Recipe Name</h1></div>
 : Andhra Spicy Mutton Curry Recipe</div>
</div>
<div id="relatedarticals_info2">
<div class="relatedarticals_info">
<div class="relatedarticals_info_bold"><h1>Author</h1></div>
 : Teluguone</div>
</div>
<div id="relatedarticals_info2">
<div class="relatedarticals_info">
<div class="relatedarticals_info_bold"><h1>Preparation Time</h1></div>
: 30 Mins</div>
</div>etc.......?

Comment: I need to get the output like this:
<h1>Recipe Name</h1>: Andhra Spicy Mutton Curry Recipe
<h1>Author</h1>: Teluguone
<h1>Preparation Time</h1>: 30 Mins etc...

Comment: Got it. You should update the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the HTML is available as string you can use jQuery's `$.parseXML` which converts into an `XMLDocument` if successfully parsed(well-formed HTML).

This object can then be traversed and manipulated using `.find()`, `.parent()` and other such traversal methods.

**Note**: That is of course, assuming you're open to doing this on the client-side.

Comment: Hi Robin,my above html string is available in a normal java class,but how can i use jquery functionality in a normal java class?can just provide me a sample code to achieve above my requirement?

Comment: @PavanKumarRagi: My answer was in jQuery since the question was tagged so. For use with Java, you would have to use JAVA-specific XML parsers available. I don't think I can recommend one off the top of my head right now.